# How to return the position of an integer if it exists at the same index in two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying create a method to detect if an array contains an integer at the same index as the other array. If so then it must return the index that the integer is at in both arrays.

#### Input:

```
array1= {"1", "2", "3", "2"}
array2 = {"1", "4", "5", "6"}
```

#### Output:

```
right

0
```

#### Input:

```
array1= {"1", "2", "3", "2"} 
array2 = {"0", "1", "5", "6"}
```

#### Output:

```
wrong

1
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
int array1[] = new int[4], array2[] = new int[4];
String position[] = new String[4];

for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{ 
     if (array2[x] == array1[x]) 
     {
          position[x] = "right";
     }
    else
     {
          for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
          {
              if (array2[x] == array1[y]) 
              {
                  position[x] = "wrong";
              }
           }
      }
}
```

Thanks you in advance :D

Comment: What should you return for position if none of them match?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean[] hasIntegerPos(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    boolean[] positions = new boolean[Math.min(a1.length, a2.length) + 1];
    positions[positions.length - 1] = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.length - 1; i++)
        if (a1[i] == a2[i]) {
            positions[i] = true;
            positions[positions.length - 1] = true;
        } else positions[i] = false;
    } return positions;
}
```

Returns a boolean array.  "true" values indicate that the positions in arrays a1 and a2 are the same, and the last value indicates whether one or more positions matched.

Comment: Calculate only once Math.min(a1.length, a2.length)

Comment: both comments incorporated into rewrite.

Comment: I don't understand the second = true.  It will be overwritten.

Comment: The second true sets the element at the last index of the array to true.  This variable indicates that at least one value is the same at some position in the two arrays.

Comment: But it is always overwritten on the last time in the loop

Comment: Good call.  Code fixed.

Comment: You still need to initialize it.  If no positions are true it is never set.

Comment: IMO, simpler, better, and probably more efficient to use a BitSet here.

Answer (score 0):

"Standard" Java practice would be to return a negative number if no match.  This assumes returning the first (or last) matching position is enough.  If you want to return all matching positions use something like @La-comadreja answer.  Makes code simple:

```
public static int firstMatch(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
   int min = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);
   for (int i=0; i<min; i++)
      if (array1[i] == array2[i])
         return i;

   return -1;  // no match found
}
```

Comment: The difference here is that you're only returning the first index, whereas I'm returning all the indices.

Answer (score 0):

first off you only need 1 for loop the second one is pointless because you say you want to know if the object in the SAME index of both arrays are the same.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x ++){
    if (array2[x] == array1[x]) 
    {
        position[x] = "right";//elements at index x of array2 and array1 are =
    }else{
        position[x] = "wrong";//elements at index x of array2 and array1 are !=
    }
```